# Changing contact_us default layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contactus

When I use [`contact_us`](https://github.com/JDutil/contact_us) gem in my rails app it uses application's layout. but I want to use another layout for contact-us page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that you can do from within the respective controller, you can specify an alternate layout template from within the action specifically.

```
# controller that calls the page
def action
  render :layout => 'other'
end
```